Visual Studio 2022 SSIS.Pipeline Error: Cannot find the connection manager with ID in the connection manager collection due to error code 0xC0010009
I have created a custom connection manager component and also dataflow component, I can see both the components in Visual Studio 2022 IDE at design time and there is no compilation error.
But when I run this, it gives the error.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Cannot find the connection manager with ID "{7966E95C-8912-4420-8AE7-854D88350C89}" in the connection manager collection due to error code 0xC0010009.
I have copied the dlls of this component at all the below location.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\160\Connections
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Connections
The strange thing is, all the other built in components are located in this folder
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Connections
But I have to manually create 160 folder for my components to appear in VS IDE at design time, it wasn't appearing until then, not sure what has changed in Visual Studio 2022.
The dlls have been registered with GACUTIL and is located here
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\SAPImportConnection
I tried changing the file "Extensions.xml" in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\UpgradeMappings
Also tried manually adding the Extension file after manually creating "UpgradeMappings" folder in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS
but with no luck, infact it started giving error at design time.
One thing I am not very comfortable and really find it odd is creating "160" folder and "DTS" subfolder under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ and just copying my custom components. After which my custom components started appearing in Visual Studio 2022 IDE at design time. I really struggled to even get at this place!
There is no documentation about this at all, and the Microsoft online help only suggest to copy files in "130" folder.

Just a stab in the dark but maybe your dlls should be registered in GAC_MSIL instead of GAC_64.

By default it went into that folder, as I built the component for target machine x64, but let me see if I can do something different, thank you.
